# Python Tesseract figuring out text orientation/transformation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

```
# Tesseract Win-Installer https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

import pytesseract
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("img.png")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
print(text)
```

the output is not even close "WX017," instead of "MX011A"

however, if I manually rearrange the characters it works. I could transform the input image and define an ROI but the orientation could be anything. It could be upside down as well.

I want to recognize curved text around a circle

1:

[image: 1]

2:

[image: 2]

3:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty difficult, as `tesseract` expects text to be minimally distorted.

One (admittedly far-fetched) possibility would be to try and detect the circle, then map it onto a rectangle.

To do this, you can reduce each letter to a non-connected blob using a blur filter and discarding grey values below a threshold; iterate until you get more or less circular blobs, then get their centers. Take several of those three by three at random, and for each triplet [calculate the center of the circle encompassing all three](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equation-of-circle-when-three-points-on-the-circle-are-given/). The average of those centers should be more or less the center of the lettering circle.

Having the center, and the approximate radius, it is relatively easy to [map the circular crown of appropriate height to a rectangle](https://mipav.cit.nih.gov/pubwiki/index.php/Transform:_Conformal_Mapping_Algorithms#Equation_8) (e.g. using [polar-to-cartesian transform](https://mathinsight.org/polar_coordinates_mapping)).

You then apply `tesseract` to the transformed rectangle.

It *should* also be possible to use autocorrelation to average and sharpen a multiple identical text along said rectangle (i.e. "MX011A   MXOI1A   MX017A" --> "MX011A").